# Design an exponential function with two variables (one independent and the 2nd dependent on the first one)

Tags: exponential-function

I need an exponential formula to predict a cost based on two variables x1 & x2 (which can be considered the product materials). If we are considering x1 (as size) independent and x2 (weight) dependent on x1, how the function will look?

For a single based variable I used so far the base function Y=a1*b1^x1.